# How To Add Event On AutoGenerate TextBox Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I developed a system in which i generated a textbox using while loop in ajax request

i have a problem

how to attached text change event on each autogenerate textbox ?

here is a code snippet .. text boxes are generate using while loop in ajax call

```
while($data<=$num){
    echo "<tr style='font-weight:bold'><td style='width:30px'>$data</td>
<td style='width:120px' ><input type='text' placeholder='Roll #'  style='width:160px' name='roll$data'></td>
<td style='width:120px'><input type='text' placeholder='Name' style='width:160px' name='roll$data'></td>



<td style='width:120px'><input type='text' placeholder='Marks' style='width:160px' name='roll$data'></td>

    </tr>";
$data++;
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide a code snippet for us to be able to help you more easily.

Comment: @Compass while($data<=$num){
 echo "<tr style='font-weight:bold'><td style='width:30px'>$data</td>
<td style='width:120px' ><input type='text' placeholder='Roll #'  style='width:160px' name='roll$data'></td>
<td style='width:120px'><input type='text' placeholder='Name' style='width:160px' name='roll$data'></td>



<td style='width:120px'><input type='text' placeholder='Marks' style='width:160px' name='roll$data'></td>

 </tr>";
$data++;
}

Comment: @Compass textboxes are generated by ajax call using while loop .. now i want to add textchange event on this

Comment: @CyberSoul Edit your question and add your code **there**

Answer (score 0):

If the text box is added after the DOM has been loaded you will need to use event delegation like so:

```
$(document).on('input', 'textarea', function () {});
```

You can replace the document and textarea selector with more relevant ones.

Comment: i want to add textchange event to textbox that are dynamically generated ... using jquery ..